# Which tables to create according to relations

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory

We are planning a new system with a new DB (MS SQL Server).

We have the following entities and the following relations:

**Entities:**
Clubs,
Chains,
PaymentTypes,
etc...

**Relations:**
Clubs-Chains (M-M);
(Clubs_Chains)-Commission (1-1);
Clubs-Chains-PaymentTypes (M-M);

- *Commission is a numeric field containing perecentage value , and is not an entity.*

We would like the DB to be normalized.
We thought about the following option, but we are not sure if it is the best solution for the scenario:

**Clubs_Chains table:**
ClubChainID PK int not null,
ClubID FK int not null,
ChainID FK int not null,
Commission int

**Clubs_Chains_PayMethod table:**
ClubChainID PK int not null,
PaymentTypeID PK int not null

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that your naming is rather inconsistent. your entity names are plural (Clubs) and singular (PaymentType). The name of the ID filed contains a plural (ClubChainsID) or a singualr(ClubId). I think it would be simpler to remember the names if you follow some simple naming conventions.

Comment: it would be nice if you supply an entity relationship diagram

Comment: Hi @miracle173 , thanks for the suggestion, I changed the naming, hopefully there is an improvement... How would you suggest to add the relational diagram to the question?

Comment: What does chain mean in this context? A chain of stores?

Comment: @miracle173, yes a chain of stores. A chain can be connected to one or many clubs and vice verse, and for each Chain-Club Connection there is a percentage commission, and at least one PaymentType.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't necessary to have a surrogate primary key on your **clubs_chains** table.

The combination of the two foreign keys in **clubs_chains** is adequate for the primary key.

You can use a foreign key constraint to ensure that your **clubs_chains_paymethod** table references an existing record in **clubs_chains** using the compound primary key.  This might be helpful since it would allow more direct joins between **clubs_chains_paymethod** and your **clubs** and **chains** tables, without sacrificing any referential integrity.

On the other hand, some people just love using a surrogate primary key, even on intersection tables.  If that is your data modelling style, then it's OK too.

Answer (score 1):

An ER diagram I deduced from your descritption. I am not sure if this is a valid interpretation of your description.  ER diagrams and the transformation of ER diagrams to relations are discussed  in this [article](http://www.fe.up.pt/~jmoreira/wwwsi/2000-01/eerm.pdf)

[image: ER diagram created with dia]

For the relations and entities labeled with ??? I did not know an appropriate name.

Comment: This seems correct, (Except for the '0' between the combined entity and the relation to 'PayMethod', which should be '1'). What would you suggest to do when translating this into tables? Are there any readings that you can recommend on how to translate the relations into tables? Thanks

Comment: Also, How did you add the diagram?

Comment: i created the diagram with [dia](http://dia-installer.de/download/index.html.en) exported it as jpeg. This I added to my post by using the image button (Ctrl+G)

Comment: the translation is simple but currently i did not know any readings. if i have more time i will search the web for an appropriate article. you can put a question in this forum if sombody knows a good article about using entity relationships diagrams.

Comment: did you know approprate nouns/verbs for the entities/relations labelde with '???' ? Then I would icorporate them int the diagram.

Comment: @Shani: i found a very good document about extended entity relatisonship  diagrams and added a link it to my post. it is the document that introduced me to EER more than 20 years ago. it also describes transforming EER to relations.

Comment: Thanks! It's a really good read, I'm going over it on my spare time - hopefully it will help with our DB plannings and execution